SSRS Subreports Not Showing
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 15.0.1103.12 (i.e. SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services). I am creating a report using the standalone Report Builder (v15.0.20283.0). I am querying an Oracle DB data source.
I have a report that I would like to create that is a collation of other reports, i.e. a collation of sub-reports. However, I am running into an issue where the sub-report(s) do not show. There is no error or any indication that there is a problem, the sub-report simply doesn't show. Each of the sub-reports is basically a Tablix, and they do have a NoRowsMessage populated, so even if no rows are returned, a message should display (and a message does display when opening the sub-report on its own).
What I would like to do, ideally, is populate the parameter of each sub-report with a parameter in the main report. So what I started with is a sub-report directly on the Body surface, and configured the subreport parameter "Year" to be associated with the main report parameter "Year".
This seems to work. However, when I add an additional subreport, nothing displays. No error message(s), no subreport(s) - nothing.
Basically, when I add a single subreport, it seems to work. Then, I add another subreport, and I get the error message below and if I refresh, no subreports display.
Exception of type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing+DataCacheUnavailableException' was thrown. The data cache for the report edit session is not valid. Rerun the report to create a new and valid data cache. (rsDataCacheMismatch)

Sometimes, I won't see a subreport when there is only one subreport as well, but I assume that is some problem with the cache after having added and then removed a second subreport. On the other hand, this does occasionally occur even when I refresh the report and I assume that clears the cache.
I've gone through all the iterations / implementations I can think of, and which I could find through a Google search, but I'm not having any luck. It seems like most of the information out there is for older versions of SQL Server Reporting Services as well, so I am left unsure why this is a problem. Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated!
